# AttributeError: Preferences instance has no attribute '__setattr__'

Tags: python, json, linux, attributeerror

My app runs on Windows and I am trying to configure it for Linux.

I get the following `AttributeError`:

> Preferences instances has no attribute 'self.**setattr**'

```
class Preferences:

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Default preferences are imported from parameters 
        file at each creation of an object.
        The database default is not automatically 
        updated (file schema.sql). On Preferences parameters change,
        schema.sql should be changed accordingly.
        """
        with open(os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'parameters.json')) as parameters:
            json_data = json.loads(parameters.read())

        # for each att(ribute) from preference file, 
        # create an attribute in Preferences Object 
        # which is a Preference object
        for att in json_data['preferences']:
          self.__setattr__(
            att,
            Preference(
              **{label: json_data['preferences'][att][label] for label in json_data['preferences'][att]}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class literally doesn't have a `__setattr__` method. What you want to do is

```
setattr(self, name, value)
```

instead of

```
self.__setattr__(name, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setattr` instead of `__setattr__`:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr